# I have to click twice on the edit button in the gridview

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

this is my code:

```
Public Sub GridView1_RowEditing(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowEditing
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCancelEditEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCancelingEdit
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1
End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowUpdating
    Dim strid As String = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("idtxt"), TextBox).Text
    Dim strFirstName As String = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("fnmaetxt"), TextBox).Text
    Dim strLastName As String = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("lnametxt"), TextBox).Text
    Dim strAdress As String = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("adresstxt"), TextBox).Text
    Dim strEmail As String = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("emtailtxt"), TextBox).Text
    Dim strPhone As String = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("phonetxt"), TextBox).Text
    Dim strBirthday As String = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("birthdaytxt"), TextBox).Text


    x.updateProfile(strid, strFirstName, strLastName, strAdress, strEmail, strBirthday, strPhone)
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1
End Sub
```

the problem is that i have to click twice on the edit button to enter the edit mode and twice on the cancel button to go back to the edit mode and when i update i have to reclick on the update to go back to the edit mode and when i reclick on it all the fields become empty..

any help?

Comment: This doesn't look like MVC. This might be far fetch, I once had something similar and it was because someone played with Page_BlockSubmit variable of the Validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to click once to get the focus, then another time to actually perfrorm the edit. A workaround i did for this issue is to handle PreviewLeftMouseButton down  in the grid, i test if the element clicked is a row element, then i have it focused and i don't claim the click to be handled.